# Django webpage loading issue

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm creating a project in Django, my admin section is working properly, and models are working properly but when I'm going to open the server to check the landing page, it shows like this attached below.

I've created another page and made that page the main landing page but that showed me the same result. Don't know what to do now.

Answer (score 0):

if you create new app in Django . You need to introduce the new path to the Django framework so that the desired page is displayed in the output.
To introduce the new route, refer to the main URLs file of the app and use include:

```
path('', include('app_name'))
```